# Rich look and feel in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles

I am searching for good samples for WPF that gives rich look and feel in WPF. Like for example a fancy TreeView Control with icons ..or Outllok like layout...

Samples that shows the real power of WPF in terms of rich look and feel..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out official wpf site http://windowsclient.net/wpf/default.aspx

There are lots of samples and videos

http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/wpfsamples/default.aspx

http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd look up microsoft.com/expression , there are usually some good materials there regarding WPF/ Blend etc.

Comment: Can I download the samples created through Microsoft Blend.Do we need Microsof Blend to open the samples?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Expression Blend product, there are several sample apps bundled in that may give you the inspiration you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the demo on [Xceed's website](http://xceed.com/) for some great examples of WPF Controls (including Grids and TreeViews). They also have a 45 day free-trial if you'd like to play with the controls on your own machine.